# remove s from permission

Tags: files, permissions, chmod

here is my file :

```
srw-rw---- 1 nfsen nfsen 0 mai   16 10:51 nfsen.comm
```

and I want to remove the `s` ,I tried comething like

```
chmod 0660 nfsen.comm
```

but  didn't work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove that `s` with `chmod` or anything else because it is not a permission. The first character in each line in `ls -l` output indicates the type of file: `-` for regular file, `s` for socket, `d` for directory, `c`(haracter) or `b`(lock) device, and so on.

You can't change the type of a file after it has been created.

Comment: okay but what does socket means ?

Comment: comments is not the place to answer that (or any other) broad question. Google it. There are many short tutorials on sockets, some even on this site!